# Delete NSTimer/UITableViewCell in real time?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, timer, nstimer

I have a `UITableView` in which I have numerous timers set on each `UITableViewCell`. Each timer starts from when a user creates a "post" on my application and should expire within 24 hours. However, I want it so that when all 24 hours is over, the `UITableViewCell` deletes itself in real time but I can't seem to figure out where or when I should be deleting the timer. I have a method that will constantly refresh the timer every second using `NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval` and it updates the timers on each `UITableViewCell` every second. However, I can't find a method or find how I can find if each timer inside each UITableViewCell is finished. Obviously I can find if the timer is finished in `viewDidLoad` but that is only called right when the view becomes active. Is there any method I am missing or anything I can use to find if a timer via the `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval` method is finished, and if it is, to delete it? Here is my code below:

```
//I have a self.offers array declared in the beginning of my class whcih will act as the UITableView data source.
var offers = [Offer]()


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    //Dequeue a "reusable" cell
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(offerCellIdentifier) as! OfferCell
    setCellContents(cell, indexPath: indexPath)
    return cell
}

func setCellContents(cell:OfferCell, indexPath: NSIndexPath!){
    let item = self.offers[indexPath.row]
    cell.offerName.text = item.offerName()
    cell.offerPoster.text = item.offerPoster()

    var expirDate: NSTimeInterval = item.dateExpired()!.doubleValue

    //Get current time and subtract it by the predicted expiration date of the cell. Subtract them to get the countdown timer.
    var timeUntilEnd = expirDate - NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970

    if timeUntilEnd <= 0 {
        //Here is where I want to delete the countdown timer but it gets difficult to do so when you are also inserting UITableViewCells and deleting them at the same time.
        self.offers.removeAtIndex(indexPath!.row)

        self.offersReference = Firebase(url:"<Database Link>")
        self.offersReference.removeValue()
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        cell.timeLeft.text = "Finished."
    }
    else{
        //Display the time left
        var seconds = timeUntilEnd % 60
        var minutes = (timeUntilEnd / 60) % 60
        var hours = timeUntilEnd / 3600

        cell.timeLeft.text = NSString(format: "%dh %dm %ds", Int(hours), Int(minutes), Int(seconds)) as String
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var timeExpired = false
    //I set up my offers array above with completion handler
    setupOffers { (result, offer) -> Void in
        if(result == true){
            //Insert each row one by one.
            var currentCount = self.offers.count
            var indexPaths: [NSIndexPath] = [NSIndexPath]()
            indexPaths.append(NSIndexPath(forRow:currentCount, inSection: 0))
            self.offers.append(offer)
            currentCount++
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.dataSource = self
    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    self.tableView.rowHeight = 145.0
}

//Called when you click on the tab
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    self.refreshTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: "refreshView:", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    //Should fire while scrolling, so we need to add the timer manually:
    //var currentRunLoop = NSRunLoop()
    //currentRunLoop.addTimer(refreshTimer, forMode: NSRunLoopCommonModes)
}

override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
    refreshTimer.invalidate()
    refreshTimer = nil
}

//Constantly refreshes the data in the offers array so that the time will continuously be updating every second on the screen.
func refreshView(timer: NSTimer){
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of misconceptions, a few problems with your code, and your description isn't clear.

If you create a timer using scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval, you don't need to, and shouldn't, add it to the runloop. The `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval` method does that for you.

If you create a repeating timer, it never "finishes." It keeps repeating forever. If instead you create a non-repeating timer, it fires once and then goes away. You don't need to delete it. Just don't keep a strong reference to it and it will be deallocated once it fires.

You say you create a timer for each table view cell, but the code you posted only creates a single timer for the view controller. You say "...it updates the timers on each UITableViewCell every second. However, I can't find a method or find how I can find if each timer inside each UITableViewCell is finished." That doesn't match the code you posted. Your code is running a timer once a second that simply tells the table view to reload it's data.

I guess you mean that you re-display a remaining time counter in each cell when your timer fires?

So, are you asking how to figure out if the time remaining for all of your cell's `item.timeLeft()` has reached zero? You haven't posted the code or the requirements for your `timeLeft()` function, so your readers can't tell what is supposed to be happening.

Comment: Hi,  thank you for letting me know about the runloop. I will fix that accordingly. With regards to the repeating timer, I want to have it repeat because I want it to update the timer in real time. If i set the `repeat:` parameter in `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval` as `false`, the timer will not update in real time. I apologize for the last portion of the question I was extremely sloppy because I didn't want to post too much code. I will edit it accordingly and try to make things more clear.

Comment: I have posted my edits above. I have taken out some misleading code and shown how my `UITableViewCells` are working. I apologize for before.  So basically what I want to do is when the `timeLeft()` has changed to 0, I want to remove that cell from the `UITableView` in real time. However, I realize that doing this in `setCellContents` isn't the best method to do this in because I also call this method when inserting into my `tableView` so I get conflicts. I was wondering if there was a method where I can find when each cell's timer hits 0 and then delete that cell entirely.

Comment: Nevermind, I have fixed it all. The code above works. Thanks for your help!