# Creating a timer to delete a tableviewcell user post?

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, firebase

I'm creating an app where users are able to make posts which are contained in a tableview, but I'm wanting the posts to be deleted after 10 minutes. All users can see the 10 minute countdown.

I found this source : [Delete NSTimer/UITableViewCell in real time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30042534/delete-nstimer-uitableviewcell-in-real-time)

They're seemingly setting up a date for the post to expire, setting up some timers to count down each second, and if that timeleft is 0, the post is deleted and the reference on firebase gets removed.

Does this not completely crash and burn if a user kills the application? So for example a user makes a post, it posts it to firebase, sends it out, the user kills the application, those timers stop, and the post is stuck forever. Surely each user needs a timer running for each post sent to them, but then who is in charge of deleting that reference on firebase?

My question is where/how is the best place to keep track of these timers? I don't know if there's some utilization of firebase that could be used here to make this more clean. I know how to use timers and how to delete the posts with the timers, but I'm just not sure how to structure this all out.

Comment: If the posts are stored on a server, it's the server's job to remove the post when the timer is up. Relying on the client device is impractical because, like you said, if the client kills the application the post will stay there forever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right that timers get killed if your app is terminated. They get suspended if your app is suspended, as well. Pretty much any time the user swaps to another app and stays there for more than a few seconds this approach won't work.

You could save an array of expire dates to user defaults, and any time the app is launched/returns to the foreground, you could check the array of expire dates. If an expire date has passed, you'd delete that post from Firebase. (Actually you'd probably save an array of dictionaries where one key was the date and another key was the record ID so you could find the record.)

You could also create local notifications using the expire date of the entry as the fire date of the notifiacation. If your app is running it would get the notification in the background and you could trigger the delete. If not it would show a message to the user and if the user asks to open the app you could then check your array of expire dates as above.

Comment: Hey there, these ideas would work for a 1-user app, but not so much for multiple users right?  Because that relies on the poster to log in to delete that post still for everyone else. 

For a multi-user app do I need to go with something like Creos said where there is a backend handling it for me? I'd like to avoid that if possible cause I'm feeling like that might be a bit above my capabilities atm.

Is there anything fundamentally wrong with giving everyone a timer that checks every second against expiration dates for current posts and doesn't show them once they're beyond that time?

Comment: Alternatively I just thought of this. Could I use firebase to only send posts out to a user that's less than 4 minutes old using an endAt query?

Comment: Multiple users? On a single device, or on multiple devices? If you're takling a single device, you will need some sort of login mechanism with a database of the messages and their expiration times, broken out by user ID. A multi-user system on a single device seems silly, though. If it's one user per device then you need a server-based database.

Comment: Using a timer that fires every second and checks against ALL messages would work, but it would not scale well as the number of messages grows. Alternately you could run though all the existing messages when you return to the foreground and create a timer for each message that fires at the moment that message expires.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I meant like multiple users on multiple devices, bad wording.

Thanks so much for the advice and help!

Comment: If you mean multiple users on multiple devices then you will need some sort of server-based database of messages and a way to present the messages for a specific user. (Along with security to prevent other users from spoofing and reading somebody else's messages, but that's a different topic.) On a single device you should only need to care about YOUR messages. (The messages for the current user.)

Answer (score 1):

There is no truly correct and 100% reliable/robust way to clean this up using any kind of CLIENT app solution. You need a backend process to handle this. Here is one possible solution if you don't want to deal with maintaining your own servers.

You could use Google App Engine and write a backend which runs a script say every X hours to clear out old entries (be careful with TZs in your timestamps, make sure everything is consistent). Depending on whether you feel you will have other processing needs in the future, it may be very much worth going this way.

For that you would need a full Google App Engine (Google Cloud) account and probably higher pay-as-you-use pricing but it will likely be more expensive for you to deal with running your own server.

For details how to approach this see here: https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/firebase-app-engine-android-studio

**From there you should look at the nice design option diagrams they've done to visualize how your client apps + firebase + app engine work together. 
https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/mobile-app-backend-services**

BTW Google uploaded fancy new tutorials (codelabs) replacing all of firebase's old docs a month ago or so. So I suspect they will very soon add a codelab with app engine integration as well (I couldn't find one yet). In the meantime, you can see the one I pasted above, it is from google's official cloud site.

Answer (score 0):

You should not rely on you client app to delete the post. As you said killing the app would result on a corrupt server.

A better solution would be to create the post with a validity date and in your app you show only valid posts. 
To update the UI, you can setup timer to trigger when the validity date is reached.

Comment: Alright so I understand how I would implement your idea for a 1 user-app.  How do I set up that timer for other users though? So User A sends out a post and user B and C get the post...in 4 minutes I'm wanting to not show that post for them anymore..they load up the app, get it from firebase, do I just have to have a timer running on everyone's app running like every second to check for current date vs. expiration dates stored for posts? Cause if someone has 4 posts currently up, I need to constantly be checking all of the posts' expiration dates constantly right?

Thanks for the helpso far

Comment: For each post you receive from the server, you setup a timer to trigger when its validity date is reached.
If it is too complicated you can check regularly on a background thread if one of the posts is not valid and ask the UI to reload on the main thread.